# Pandas rolling covariance by group (Rolling.cov)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, rolling-computation

can anyone give me an example on how to use the Rolling.cov function:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.cov.html

I would like to calculate the 90 days rolling covariance between RE and MA by id. I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
df.groupby(['id'])[['RE','MA']].rolling(90).cov()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `.set_index()` to include `Date` in the dataframe.
2. For this example, you need to pass an argument `min_periods`. For example, you can pass `min_periods=0`.
3. Finally, it depends on how you want to structure the data, but you can pass `.unstack(2)` or `.reset_index()` depending on the desired output. The former takes the 3rd column in the newly created multi-index and transforms from rows to columns. The latter just tkaes the three indexed columns out of the index and makes them normal columns:

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                  'RE' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                  'MA' : [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
                  'Date' : ['01-01-2020','02-15-2020','04-01-2020','05-15-2020','06-01-2020','07-15-2020',
                           '09-01-2020','10-15-2020','12-01-2020','12-15-2020']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date').groupby(['id'])[['RE','MA']].rolling(90, min_periods=0).cov().unstack(2)
df
Out[24]: 
                      RE                    MA           
                      MA        RE          MA         RE
id Date                                                  
A  2020-01-01        NaN       NaN         NaN        NaN
   2020-02-15   5.000000  0.500000   50.000000   5.000000
   2020-04-01  10.000000  1.000000  100.000000  10.000000
   2020-05-15  16.666667  1.666667  166.666667  16.666667
   2020-06-01  25.000000  2.500000  250.000000  25.000000
B  2020-07-15        NaN       NaN         NaN        NaN
   2020-09-01   5.000000  0.500000   50.000000   5.000000
   2020-10-15  10.000000  1.000000  100.000000  10.000000
   2020-12-01  16.666667  1.666667  166.666667  16.666667
   2020-12-15  25.000000  2.500000  250.000000  25.000000
```

---

with `reset_index()` instead of `unstack(2)`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                  'RE' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                  'MA' : [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
                  'Date' : ['01-01-2020','02-15-2020','04-01-2020','05-15-2020','06-01-2020','07-15-2020',
                           '09-01-2020','10-15-2020','12-01-2020','12-15-2020']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date').groupby(['id'])[['RE','MA']].rolling(90, min_periods=0).cov().reset_index()
df
Out[25]: 
   id       Date level_2         RE          MA
0   A 2020-01-01      RE        NaN         NaN
1   A 2020-01-01      MA        NaN         NaN
2   A 2020-02-15      RE   0.500000    5.000000
3   A 2020-02-15      MA   5.000000   50.000000
4   A 2020-04-01      RE   1.000000   10.000000
5   A 2020-04-01      MA  10.000000  100.000000
6   A 2020-05-15      RE   1.666667   16.666667
7   A 2020-05-15      MA  16.666667  166.666667
8   A 2020-06-01      RE   2.500000   25.000000
9   A 2020-06-01      MA  25.000000  250.000000
10  B 2020-07-15      RE        NaN         NaN
11  B 2020-07-15      MA        NaN         NaN
12  B 2020-09-01      RE   0.500000    5.000000
13  B 2020-09-01      MA   5.000000   50.000000
14  B 2020-10-15      RE   1.000000   10.000000
15  B 2020-10-15      MA  10.000000  100.000000
16  B 2020-12-01      RE   1.666667   16.666667
17  B 2020-12-01      MA  16.666667  166.666667
18  B 2020-12-15      RE   2.500000   25.000000
19  B 2020-12-15      MA  25.000000  250.000000
```